# Redux form, loses focus after keypress?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Im experiencing a bit of a weird problem.
I have a form where I have an input field, but after i trigger an onChange event with a keypress it loses focus from the input field...

```
{editPhoneEnabled && <Field
        name="phoneNumber"
        component={phoneFieldRenderer}
        validate={[Validator.required, Validator.phone]}
      />}

const phoneFieldRenderer = ({ input }) => {
  return (
    <ReactTelInput {...input} />
  )
}
```

I've seen this example setup where the problem occurs (https://codepen.io/invisiblecomma/pen/wqLaZQ), but i've done the similar as you can see, but it still doesnt work?

Any ideas out there to help me understand what is going on?

The whole component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, getFormValues } from 'redux-form';
import { Col, FormGroup } from 'reactstrap';
import { t } from 'Utilities/i18n';
import Validator from 'Utilities/validation';
import Button from 'Components/Forms/Button';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import ReactTelInput from 'react-telephone-input';

const formName = 'PhoneVerifyForm';

const performPhoneVerificationMutation = gql`
  mutation registerPage_userPhoneVerification($input: RegisterPhoneVerificationInput!) {
    userPhoneVerification(input: $input) {
      errors {
        field
        messages
      }
      phoneNumberVerificationSid
      verified
    }
  }
`;

// TODO props: unconfirmedUserId, phoneNumberVerificationSid, initialValues, callback
const PhoneVerifyForm = (props) => {
  const [editPhoneEnabled, setEditPhoneEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [codeSend, setCodeSend] = useState(props.phoneNumberVerificationSid !== undefined);
  const [performPhoneVerification, { data:performPhoneVerificationData }] = useMutation(performPhoneVerificationMutation);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (performPhoneVerificationData && performPhoneVerificationData.userPhoneVerification) {
      const {userPhoneVerification} = performPhoneVerificationData;

      if(userPhoneVerification.errors.length === 0) {
        setErrors([])
        if (editPhoneEnabled) {
          editPhoneEnabled(false);
        }

        setCodeSend(userPhoneVerification.phoneNumberVerificationSid !== undefined);

        if(userPhoneVerification.verified !== undefined) {
          props.callback(props.formValues.phone);
        }
      } else {
        setErrors(userPhoneVerification.errors)
      }
    }
  }, [performPhoneVerificationData, ])

  function handleSubmit(values) {
    if (editPhoneEnabled) {
      // update phone number
      return performPhoneVerification({
        variables: {
          input: {
            unconfirmedUserId: props.unconfirmedUserId,
            phone: values.phoneNumber,
          },
        },
      });
    } else if (!codeSend) {
      // send new code
      return performPhoneVerification({
        variables: {
          input: {
            unconfirmedUserId: props.unconfirmedUserId,
            channel: values.channel,
          },
        },
      });
    }
    // else validate code
    return performPhoneVerification({
      variables: {
        input: {
          unconfirmedUserId: props.unconfirmedUserId,
          code: values.code,
        },
      },
    });
  }

  const handleEditPhone = () => {
    setEditPhoneEnabled(!editPhoneEnabled);
    setCodeSend(false);
  };

  const phoneFieldRenderer = ({ input }) => {
    return (
      <ReactTelInput {...input} />
    )
  }


  return (
    <form className="row" onSubmit={props.handleSubmit(handleSubmit)}>
      {!codeSend && <Col style={{background: 'pink'}}>
        <p>{t('select channel')}</p>
        <FormGroup row className="indented-form-group">
          <Col>
            <label>
              <Field
                name="channel"
                component="input"
                type="radio"
                value="sms"
                validate={Validator.required}
              />
              {t('Sms')}
            </label>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={6}>
            <label>
              <Field
                name="channel"
                component="input"
                type="radio"
                value="phone"
                validate={Validator.required}
              />
              {t('phone')}
            </label>
          </Col>
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>}

      {codeSend && <Col style={{background: 'yellow'}}>
        <FormGroup row className="indented-form-group">
          <Field
            labelClassname="required"
            label={t('Code')}
            name="code"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            validate={[Validator.required]}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>}

      <Col style={{background: 'red'}}>
        <FormGroup row className="indented-form-group">
          {!editPhoneEnabled && <div>
            <span>PHONE PLACEHOLDER</span><br />
            <span onClick={handleEditPhone}>Edit phone number</span>
          </div>}

          {editPhoneEnabled && <Field
            name="phoneNumber"
            component={phoneFieldRenderer}
            validate={[Validator.required, Validator.phone]}
          />}
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>

      <Col>
        <FormGroup row className="indented-form-group">
          <Button submit disabled={props.submitting || props.invalid}>
            {editPhoneEnabled ? t('Change phone number') : codeSend ? t('Validate code') : t('Send code')}
          </Button>
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>
    </form>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  formValues: getFormValues(formName)(state) || {}, //This basically gives us the form values in the props and it gets updated on keydown.
});

const decoratedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PhoneVerifyForm)

export default (reduxForm({
  form: formName,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  shouldAsyncValidate: ({ trigger }) => ['blur'].includes(trigger),
})(decoratedComponent));
```

Comment: Could you the whole Component where you render `<Field />`?

Comment: Sure, i've updated the answer with the whole component

Comment: Something in your code causes the whole component to re-render **onEachKeyPress** ... this could be in your `useEffect` ... I'd suggest you put a `console.log` inside it and see if it gets executed per key press

Comment: Found the error, I had to place the phoneFieldRenderer const outside the component

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue.

- In my previous project, I used class components but there I didn't face this issue.
- But in functional components, to fix this issue you need to put the `phoneFieldRenderer` function outside the component (as @envy mentioned)